# Extracting all nouns, verbs and adjectives from a large text dataset

Tags: java, performance, natural-language-processing

For a project I am using the yelp dataset (found here: https://www.yelp.com/dataset) to create a Hashset of all verbs, nouns and adjectives found in the restaurant reviews. I have it up and running using the stanford nlp pipeline, however it is quite slow (takes about 1 hour to process 10000 reviews) and the dataset contains a few million reviews. I am not an advanced programmer, I usually barely get it working so I really need help increasing the performance of my program. General coding advice is very much appreciated as well!

My code is as structured as follows:
I have a MyCorpus class that has a function review_loader(). This function loads one review ( a json object) and puts the relevant data in a class named review. review contains a function that performs the pipeline operation and returns all nouns, verbs and adjectives of the review as a HashSet, I then add this hashset to a global hashset which will contain all nouns, verbs and adjectives of the yelp dataset.

Code for the relevant functions can be seen below:

**Review.java**

```
public class review {
private  String text;
private String business_id;
private int stars;
private ArrayList<String> listOfSentences = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> pos_tags = new ArrayList<String>();
private HashSet<String> all_terms = new HashSet<String>();

public review() {
}
public HashSet<String> find_terms(StanfordCoreNLP pipeline) {
CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument(text);
pipeline.annotate(doc);
for(int f = 0; f <doc.sentences().size(); f++) {
    for (int d = 0; d < doc.sentences().get(f).tokens().size(); d++) {
        String tag = doc.sentences().get(f).posTags().get(d);
        CoreLabel word = doc.sentences().get(f).tokens().get(d);
        if (tag.contains("VB") == true|| tag.contains("JJ") == true || tag.contains("NN") == true);{
            String pattern ="[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
            // Create a Pattern object
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            // Now create matcher object.
            Matcher m = r.matcher(word.originalText());
            if (m.find() || word.originalText() == "") {

            } else {
               all_terms.add(word.originalText());
            }
        }

    }
}
return all_terms;


}
```

**MyCorpus.java**

```
public class MyCorpus{

private String filelocation_review;
private String filelocation_business;
private String filelocation_pos;
private ArrayList<String> restaurants = new ArrayList<String>();
private Set<String> allTerms = new HashSet<String>();


public MyCorpus(String filelocation_review, String filelocation_business, String filelocation_pos) {
    this.filelocation_review = filelocation_review;
    this.filelocation_business = filelocation_business;
    this.filelocation_pos = filelocation_pos;

}
    public void review_loader() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int counter = 0;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // set the list of annotators to run
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse");
    // set a property for an annotator, in this case the coref annotator is being
    // set to use the neural algorithm
    props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
    // build pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(filelocation_pos);
    InputStream is_r = new FileInputStream(filelocation_review);
    Reader r_r = new InputStreamReader(is_r, "UTF-8");
    Gson gson_r = new GsonBuilder().create();
    JsonStreamParser p = new JsonStreamParser(r_r);
    while (p.hasNext()) {
        counter += 1;
        JsonElement e = p.next();
        if (e.isJsonObject()) {
            review review = gson_r.fromJson(e, review.class);
            // This if statement checks if the review belongs to a restaurant by matching the business id to a list of all business_id's of a restaurant created previously
            if (restaurants.contains(review.get_id())) {
                HashSet<String> review_terms = review.find_terms(pipeline);
                allTerms.addAll(review_terms);
                System.out.println("size:" + allTerms.size() + "reviews processed: " + counter);            
            }
            }

        }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // WHEN YOU RUN THE FILE CHANGE THE 3 FILELOCATIONS OF THE MYCORPUS CLASS!
    MyCorpus yelp_dataset = new MyCorpus("E:\\review.json", "E:\\business.json", "C:\\Users\\Ruben\\git\\Heracles\\stanford-postagger-2018-10-16\\models\\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");
    ArrayList<String> restaurants = yelp_dataset.business_identifier();
    yelp_dataset.review_loader();
    }
```

If there is anything that is unclear or seems weird, please do ask and thank you for taking the time to read this question.

Kind regards,
Ruben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to what @dariosicily mentioned already:

### Performance

If you just need to find out a part-of-speech of each word and do not need to [build a phrase-structure tree of sentences](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/parse.html), you need only to specify 3 annotations (without `parse`):

`props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos");`

I assume this can give you a significant boost in performance.

Since you are not doing [coreference resolution](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html), you don't need this line either:

> ```
> props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
> ```

### Incorrect if-block

> ```
> if (tag.contains("VB") == true|| tag.contains("JJ") == true || tag.contains("NN") == true);{
>             String pattern ="[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
> ...
> }
> ```

You should remove the semicolon before the curly bracket, since currently, it terminates the if-block (and makes it empty), so the instructions inside the curly brackets will always be executed! The code above is now equal to the following:

```
if (tag.contains("VB") == true|| tag.contains("JJ") == true || tag.contains("NN") == true){
    /* Doing nothing */
}

{
    String pattern ="[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
...
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct to remark about the semicolon, I have not added it because for me it was a typo due to a bad paste and copy, anyway in the doubt better to advise about it the OP.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I didn't realize I didn't need those functions, those took 80% of all run time of the program! I was now able to run the program within ~4 hours.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review, here some suggestions about your code:

> ```
> public class review { ... }
> ```

Java classnames always begin with uppercase letter so rename it to `Review`.

> ```
> private ArrayList<String> restaurants = new ArrayList<String>();
> ```

In java language it is preferable using if possible an interface like `List`  on the left part of the assignment so if you change the concrete class implementing the interface you don't notice the change in your code like below:

```
private List<String> restaurants = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Same approach from returning value from method:

> ```
> public HashSet<String> find_terms(StanfordCoreNLP pipeline) { ... }
> ```

Use instead:

```
public Set<String> find_terms(StanfordCoreNLP pipeline) { ... }
```

You have this method and `doc.sentences()` seems me a `List`:

> ```
> for(int f = 0; f <doc.sentences().size(); f++) {
>     for (int d = 0; d < doc.sentences().get(f).tokens().size(); d++) {
>         String tag = doc.sentences().get(f).posTags().get(d);
>         CoreLabel word = doc.sentences().get(f).tokens().get(d);
>         if (tag.contains("VB") == true|| tag.contains("JJ") == true || tag.contains("NN") == true);{
>            String pattern ="[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
>            // Create a Pattern object
>            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
>            // Now create matcher object.
>            Matcher m = r.matcher(word.originalText());
>            if (m.find() || word.originalText() == "") {
>            } else {
>            all_terms.add(word.originalText());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Rewrite it in a more readable way:

```
for(Sentence sentence : doc.sentences()) {
    for (int d = 0; d < sentence.token.size(); ++d) {
        String tag = sentence.posTags().get(d);
        CoreLabel word = sentence.tokens().get(d);
        //other instructions
    }
}
```

The boolean condition:

> ```
> tag.contains("VB") == true|| tag.contains("JJ") == true || tag.contains("NN") == true
> ```

You can rewrite it like this:

```
tag.contains("VB") || tag.contains("JJ") || tag.contains("NN")
```

Your pattern:

> ```
> String pattern ="[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
> Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
> ```

You are calculating it for every iteration of the loop, put it outside your loop:

```
String pattern ="[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for(Sentence sentence : doc.sentences()) {
    for (int d : sentence.token.size()) {
        String tag = sentence.posTags().get(d);
        CoreLabel word = sentence.tokens().get(d);
        //other instructions
    }
}
```

The if else you are using:

> ```
> if (m.find() || word.originalText() == "") {
> } else {
>    all_terms.add(word.originalText());
> }
> ```

You are doing an error here using the operator `==` and not the `equals` method for comparing strings; rewrite the method like this:

```
if (!m.find() && !word.originalText().equals("")) {
   all_terms.add(word.originalText());
}
```

Comment: What is `for (int d : sentence.token.size())`? Did they introduce a foreach integer up to integer in one of the last relases?

Comment: @mtj Thanks , I wrote a stupid thing and I fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I incorporated your and the other commenters notes and it works like a charm! I really appreciate the general notes for better code

Comment: @RubenEschauzier You are welcome, if you have other questions post them on the Code Review site.